# $(X^2-1)^2+(X^2-1)-12=0$ has 2 solutions only or 3?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am asked to solve for X using substitution:

$(X^2-1)^2+(X^2-1)-12=0$

Let $U = X^2-1$

$U^2+U-12=0$

$U^2+4U-3U-12=0$

$U(U+4)-3(U+4)=0$

$(U+4)(U-3)$

Then:

$U-3=0$

$U=3$

$X^2-1=3$

$X^2=4$

$X=\pm2$

This is the provided solution by my textbook.

However:

$U+4=0$

$U=-4$

$X^2-1=-4$

$X^2=-3$

$X=i\sqrt{3}$

My textbook does not provide $X=i\sqrt{3}$ as a solution. Why is $X=i\sqrt{3}$ not a solution in addition to $\pm2$?

Comment: Your book probably wants the real solutions. Note that if you choose to include the complex solutions, you should also include $-i\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $X^2=-3$, this does not mean that $X=i\sqrt 3$. There is another solution $X=-i\sqrt 3$ that you have neglected. In either case, the reason your textbook might not have included $X=\pm 2,\pm i\sqrt 3$ as all four solutions is because it was only seeking for real solutions, of which there are only $\pm 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your textbook is asking for only real solutions and $\pm2$ are only real solutions while $i\sqrt{3}$ is an imaginary solution